# Import an Excel worksheet into Access using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to import an Excel spreadsheet into Access using some simple VBA code. The issue I have run into is there are 2 worksheets in the Excel file, and I need the 2nd worksheet to be imported. Is it possible to specify the needed worksheet in the VBA code?

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim dlg As FileDialog
Set dlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With dlg
.Title = "Select the Excel file to import"
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Filters.Clear
.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls", 1
.Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*", 2

If .Show = -1 Then
StrFileName = .SelectedItems(1)
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel8, "COR Daily", StrFileName, True
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End With

End Sub
```

Should I set StrFileName to `'StrFileName'&'.Worksheetname'` ? Is that the proper naming scheme for that?

something like:

```vb
StrFileName = StrFileName & ".WorkSheetName"
```

Answer (score 16):

Pass the sheet name with the Range parameter of the [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214134%28office.12%29.aspx).  See the box titled "Worksheets in the Range Parameter" near the bottom of that page.

This code imports from a sheet named "temp" in a workbook named "temp.xls", and stores the data in a table named "tblFromExcel".

```vb
Dim strXls As String
strXls = CurrentProject.Path & Chr(92) & "temp.xls"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, , "tblFromExcel", _
    strXls, True, "temp!"
```

Comment: something as simple as an exclamation mark can make all the difference.  Thanxs.

Comment: You must note that, if the target table already exists in the Access database and has the same structure, the imported data will be appended to it.

Comment: Its now working m having same table structure as in excel but every time its created new table